# GCE Image suddenly not found

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I'm running kubernetes on GCE. I used kube-up.sh to create the cluster and the nodes and masters are all running the image `gci-stable-56-9000-84-2`. I deleted a few nodes today which triggered the autoscaler to create new ones. But they failed with the following error.

> Instance 'kubernetes-minion-30gb-20180131-9jwn' creation failed: The
>   resource
>   'projects/google-containers/global/images/gci-stable-56-9000-84-2' was
>   not found (when acting as 'REDACTED')

Is it possible this image was deleted somehow? I don't think I changed any access controls or permissions for any service accounts.

The image is present on this page:
https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/release-notes#cos-stable-56-9000-84-2

Answer (score 0):

This error could be due to authentication issues. Re-authenticate to the gcloud command-line tool with command ‘gcloud auth login’

It could be as well that the Kubernetes Engine service account has been deleted or edited. Check this: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#error_404